# Why is my Redo Log Apply service "spotty"?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, connectivity, dataguard, transaction-log

I have a 12c Dataguard configuration between `apple` (primary) and `orange` (physical standby). The following is my entry in ldap:

```
apple=
(DESCRIPTION_LIST=
 (DESCRIPTION=
  (ADDRESS_LIST=
   (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=apple_home)(PORT=15940))
   (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=orange_home)(PORT=15940)))
    (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=virtual_apple)(FAILOVER_MODE=(TYPE=SESSION)(METHOD=basic)))
 )
  (DESCRIPTION=
   (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=apple_home)(PORT=15940))
    (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=apple)(FAILOVER_MODE=(TYPE=SESSION)(METHOD=basic)))
 )
)
```

My goal with this is to allow clients to `sqlplus user@apple` regardless of which database is the current primary. This is why you see `virtual_apple` in the connect string, it is a service created that only runs on current primary. I added the second `DESCRIPTION` so that in the event of a switchover where `apple` is the standby, Broker can connect from `orange` to `apple` (see `orange` parameter below). It will otherwise fail to connect because it will be looking for the `virtual_apple` service on the standby which is undesirable due to the fact that users would then be redirected to the standby when running `sqlplus user@apple`.

The problem that I have been encountering is that redo shipping and applying seems "spotty". One minute there will no problems and the next I will get `ORA-16857: standby disconnected from redo source for longer than specified threshold` and redo logs stop applying. I then set `TransportDisconnectedThreshold='120'` as I have found in articles. However, the problem persists.

I suspect this is due to my network service name description. Perhaps Broker takes too long trying to reach the wrong service name which throws `ORA-16857` but then hits the right one but then loses it again. Is my connection string wrong/problematic? Is there a parameter I could add to help solve this issue? Is my issue elsewhere?

On orange:

```
log_archive_dest_2='service="apple"','ASYNC NOAFFIRM delay=0 optional compression=disable max_failure=0 max_connections=1 reopen=300 db_unique_name="apple" net_timeout=30','valid_for=(online_logfile,all_roles)'
```

Comment: Have you created database role based services? https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/RACAD/srvctladmin.htm#RACAD5013

Comment: Also provide value of log_archive_dest_2 parameter from both sites inclusing `DGMGRL>show configuration`.